# Golang channel in a struct: Can it be directional when passed to a function?

Tags: go, struct, channel

When passing a channel to a function, I know you can specify the direction that channel may use the channel for; for example,

```
func MyFunc(ch chan<- string) {
    ch <- "Hello"
}
```

"ch" can only be used by MyFunc to send strings to a receiver elsewhere and MyFunc cannot listen for messages from ch.

To simplify creating a dynamic number of channels to some number of goroutines, I created a struct containing channels.

```
type ChanStruct struct {
    chMessages chan string
}
```

Then I instantiate a structs:

```
var slcChanStruct []ChanStruct
for a:= 0; a <=2; a++ {
    var tmpChanStruct ChanStruct
    tmpChanStruct.chMessages = make(chan string)
    slcChanStruct = append(slcChanStruct, tmpChanStruct)
}
```

Now I have 3 structs I can individually read/write with a channel by ranging over a slice of structs. But when I send them off to goroutines:

```
for a:=0; a <=2; a++{
    go SomeFunc(slcChanStruct[a])
}
```

...is there a way to add a bit of safety by specifying that the goroutines can only, for example, send using the ChanStruct.ch channel?

NOTE the reason I was doing this is that if I don't know how many channels I'll need for a parallel set of processes (the number of processes are passed as a command line argument) using a struct with channels means I can create a slice that can be passed to any number of goroutines and directly access them individually by ranging over them; before, I had to create a set number of channels if I wanted to individually read from a number of goroutines. I'd like to add some safety to this by specifying that processes can only use a channel a certain way, like I could when using individual channels (individual channels mean I can do something like telling a particular goroutine to quit without other goroutines intercepting it). Is there a more idiomatic way to do this if I can't add directionality to functions using the channel in a struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On top of @Adrian's suggestions, if you have to ensure one way communication on a channel, you can always use an anonymous function:

```
for a:=0; a <=2; a++{
  go func f(ch <-string) {
    SomeFunc(ch)
  }(slcChanStruct[a].chMessages)
}
```

Note that you'll have to pass the channel to `SomeFunc` instead of the struct.

If you still want to perform both way communication on your channel, you can re assign the channel to a one directional type:

```
type ChanStruct struct {
    chMessages chan string
}

type ChanStructRecv struct {
    chMessages <-chan string
}

// Update SomeFunc type:

func SomeFunc(s ChanStructRecv) {
  // ...
}
```

Finally, the loop can be modified similarly:

```
for a:=0; a <=2; a++{
  go func f(s ChanStruct) {
    var sr ChanStructRecv
    sr.chMessages = s.chMessages
    SomeFunc(sr)
  }(slcChanStruct[a])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways, depending on your particular situation:

- Pass the channel instead of the struct, and make the channel parameter directional as in your first example
- Don't expose the channel directly, just expose a struct method to write to it (if there's no method to read from it, it's effectively directional)
- Make the channel struct member directional:

E.g.

```
type myStruct struct {
    c chan <- bool
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had thought about the third example, but if I make the struct member directional, how would I read from it in the receiver side? Wouldn't that make it impossible?

Comment: The receiver would have to keep its own copy of the channel which is either not directional, or receive-only, the same as you would have to with your original example passing a directional channel directly to the function.